# Force Access Control on web server resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis

I have a web application deployed on IIS with IP domain say `192.168.0.105:1009`.
User has login authentication in application with userid and password with userid and password saved in database.

There is a folder in application say `MyResource`. How can i control the access control of this folder to any unauthorized user.

If someone type the url `192.168.0.105:1009/MyResource/1.xls`, it should validate the user authentication. If user not authorised, access should be denied.

Comment: Put web.conifig in that folder with required authorization tag.

Comment: you should use authentication and authorization in your web.config file and do roll management in your application.

Comment: For detailed explanation please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below explanation.

> Configure Access to a Specific File and Folder, Set up forms-based authentication.

Request any page in your application to be redirected to Logon.aspx automatically.

In the `Web.config` file, type or paste the following code.

This code grants all users access to the `Default1.aspx page` and the `Subdir1 folder`.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms" >
            <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" protection="None" path="/" timeout="20" >
            </forms>
        </authentication>
<!-- This section denies access to all files in this application except for those that you have not explicitly specified by using another setting. -->
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" /> 
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
<!-- This section gives the unauthenticated user access to the Default1.aspx page only. It is located in the same folder as this configuration file. -->
        <location path="default1.aspx">
        <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
        </system.web>
        </location>
<!-- This section gives the unauthenticated user access to all of the files that are stored in the Subdir1 folder.  -->
        <location path="subdir1">
        <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
        </system.web>
        </location>
</configuration>
```

Users can open the Default1.aspx file or any other file saved in the Subdir1 folder in your application. They will not be redirected automatically to the Logon.aspx file for authentication.

Repeat configuration Step to identify any other pages or folders for which you want to permit access by unauthenticated users.

For more Reference check Microsoft support page - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301240

And also you can check http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authorization

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. How web.config knows the authorized and unauthorized user. I mean what define the authorized and unauthorized user for web.config.

Comment: @RajeevKumar you have to define form authntication ticket code on login page button click - for reference check -> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13872/Form-authentication-and-authorization-in-ASP-NET